# SQL Server Agent in Stopped State

Tags: sql-server

I have a local install of SQL Developer Edition, which I upgraded from SQL Express. I'd like to schedule a couple of test jobs, I went down to the SQL Server Agent in Management Studio and it had a nasty red cross over it. I scheduled a test job but its doing nothing and shows nothing in job history.
When I right click it and select start, it doesn't work either.

[Snapshot of SSMS screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Cxw.png)

PS. I am using SSMS 2016 Developer version.

Comment: Can you please share the error, "you are facing.?

Answer (score 2):

While I was experimenting to solve this issue, I changed the account of sql server agent via SQL configuration manger and made it same as SQL Server. SQL agent is working now!